# How to make my css webkit animation stop changing

Tags: css, webkit

I want to make my image stop changing.

How can I do this?

Demo: http://forum.8s.nl

Comment: Which image? Be more clear, please. If you are referring to the top image, just delete this line: `-webkit-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In header.css line 37 please remove

```
-webkit-animation: slide 70s linear infinite;
```

header.css location

```
http://forum.8s.nl/cache/themes/theme4/header.css
```